# The profiler has requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this process on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, clr

I'm running an Identity server 4 project on IIS and suddenly it ran into this error :

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - The profiler has requested that the CLR instance not load the profiler into this process.  Profiler CLSID: '{cf0d821e-299b-5307-a3d8-b283c03916da}'.  Process ID (decimal): 11560.  Message ID: [0x2516].

In the event viewer I saw this error. 
My application won't run anymore and deployment on IIS doesn't work either. 
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you or someone else been running profiling sessions on the machine? In any case I believe this is a benign warning and not the reason it doesn’t work.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It works on kestrel mode and no one else has been running profiling sessions , it's on my local machine and I working on it by my own

Comment: This is an INFO message, not ERROR, logged by .NET runtime in the event viewer on the .NET Agent profiler skipping to be loaded into a .NET process when the .NET application is not specified to be monitored. This improvement helps avoiding unnecessary loading of .NET Agent profiler into a .NET process. You may have some .NET applications that are being restarted frequently but not being specified to be monitored. If desired, you could consider creating a custom view in event viewer to filter out these INFO message from .NET runtime.